# Pyspark Use groupByKey/mapValues more than once in one line

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm using PySpark and I'm looking for a way to use more than once groupByKey/mapValues method.

Given :

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(u'04896f3765094732a478ba63dd42c785', 
                       u'2016-01-01', 
                       u'2', 
                       u'1404.0', 
                       u'2016-333', 
                       u'2016-48', 
                       u'2016-11', 
                        '2016-11-28'),

                      (u'kldmm584753dljkdhggdklkfj32a478ba63dd422574', 
                       u'2016-01-14', 
                       u'6', 
                       u'2000.0', 
                       u'2016-333', 
                       u'2016-48', 
                       u'2016-11', 
                        '2016-11-28')

                    ])
```

I want to group my rdd by the 4TH element ('2016-333' here), and get len, sum, etc..
My codes :

```
(rdd
 .map(lambda x : (x[4], x[0]))
 .groupByKey()
 .mapValues(len)
 .collect())

Output : [(u'2016-333', 2)]

(rdd
 .map(lambda x : (x[4], float(x[3])))
 .groupByKey()
 .mapValues(sum)
 .collect())

Output : [(u'2016-333', 3404.0)]

(rdd
 .map(lambda x : (x[4], int(x[2])))
 .groupByKey()
 .mapValues(sum)
 .collect())

Output : [(u'2016-333', 8)]
```

My question : Is there a way to do this in one go ? 
The expected output is :

```
[(u'2016-333', 2, 3404.0, 8)]
```

Thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `reduceByKey` as in the [wordcount example](http://www.mccarroll.net/blog/pyspark2/). Here, your values are a 3-part tuple, and your reducer would be a summation of the elements.

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[4], (1, float(x[3]), int(x[2])))).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1], x[2] + y[2])).collect()
```

Comment: David I have an output like this ,
[('one', (10, 1)), ('two', (10, 1)), ('two', (10, 1)), ('three', (10, 1)), ('three', (10, 1)), ('three', (10, 1))]
so when i ran on tuple like rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:  (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1])).collect() it gave me output
but when i tried to sum only second element of tuple  wordPairsRDD.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:  (x[1] + y[1])).collect() it creates error TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable..please let me know how to get only second element sum without using extra map before reduceByKey

Comment: As a rule of thumb when using `reduceByKey` your input and output key format needs to be the same. Here, your input format is a tuple, but your output format is a int. Say you have (1,5), (2,4), (2,6). It would first reduce the first two pairs to be 9. Then it would try and reduce 9 and (2, 6). But, you function takes 2 tuples, not a tuple and an int. Try `lambda x, y: (0, x[1] + y[1])`. This way your doing the addition in the last element of your tuple. After `reducingByKey`, pull this value out

Comment: Thanks David...:)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible:

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[4], float(x[3]), int(x[2]))).toDF(["key", "x3", "x2"]) \
    .groupBy("key").agg({"*": "count", "x3": "sum", "x2": "sum"}).rdd
```

or

```
rdd.map(lambda x: (x[4], np.array([1, float(x[3]), int(x[2])]))) \
    .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y) \
    .mapValues(lambda x: (int(x[0]) , int(x[1]), x[2]))
```

Comment: LostInOverflow Thx ! But there is no way to do this without using DataFrames ? (Only rdds)